# From traditional loop to list comprehension

Tags: python, list, loops, fibonacci

I am working on a challenge and I would like to convert my code (that works) to a more efficient one. Given a number prod (for product), we search two Fibonacci numbers `F(n)` and `F(n+1)` verifying `F(n) * F(n+1) = prod` or not.

This is my original code that works

```
def productFib(prod):
    fibonacci_numbers = [0, 1]
    for i in range(2,prod+1):
        fibonacci_numbers.append(fibonacci_numbers[i-1]+fibonacci_numbers[i-2])

    pairing = [[fibonacci_numbers[i], fibonacci_numbers[i+1]] for i in range((len(fibonacci_numbers)-1))]
    for ind, pair in enumerate(pairing):
        if pair[0]*pair[1] ==prod:
            ans=[pair[0], pair[1], True]
            return ans
        elif all(pair[0]*pair[1] !=prod for pair in pairing)==True:
            match=next(x for x in pairing if x[0]*x[1]>prod)
            ans=[match[0], match[1], False]
            return ans
            break
```

```py
def productFib(prod):

    fibonacci_numbers = [0, 1]
    for i in range(2, prod+1):
        fibonacci_numbers.append(fibonacci_numbers[i-1]+fibonacci_numbers[i-2])

    pairing = [[fibonacci_numbers[i], fibonacci_numbers[i+1], True] if [fibonacci_numbers[i]*fibonacci_numbers[i+1]]==prod \
    else [next(fibonacci_numbers[n] for n in range(len(fibonacci_numbers)-1) if fibonacci_numbers[n]*fibonacci_numbers[n+1]>prod), next(fibonacci_numbers[n+1] for n in range(len(fibonacci_numbers)-1) if fibonacci_numbers[n]*fibonacci_numbers[n+1]>prod) , False] if all(fibonacci_numbers[i]*fibonacci_numbers[i+1] !=prod) ==True \
    for i in range((len(fibonacci_numbers)-1))]

    return pairing
```

I expect it to return:

```
[F(n), F(n+1), true] or [F(n), F(n+1), false]
```

Depending on a number prod (for product), we search two Fibonacci numbers F(n) and F(n+1) verifying -> F(n) * F(n+1) = prod

Comment: List comprehensions are fine for simple transformations. As the computations becomes more complex, list comprehensions start to severely damage readability.

Comment: Regardless of whether it is a good idea to do this as a list comprehension or not (after all, you said it's for a challenge) - what does your current implementation returns (i.e. where does it fail)?

Comment: SyntaxError in the for i in range((len(fibonacci_numbers)-1)) just at the end.

I know this list comprehension is a bit "crazy" but it is also nice to practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this rework mimics your original code but is significantly simpler:

```
def productFib(target):
    fibonacci = [0, 1]

    while True:
        product = fibonacci[0] * fibonacci[1]

        if product >= target:
            return fibonacci + [product == target]

        fibonacci[:] = fibonacci[1], sum(fibonacci)

print(productFib(272))
print(productFib(273))
print(productFib(274))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
[13, 21, False]
[13, 21, True]
[21, 34, False]
>
```

You've implied two goals: "more efficient" and "list comprehension" -- I've gone with "more efficient".

Answer (score 1):

Usually, there are some ways to simplify a question:

1. Another simpler and more efficient way
2. more pythonic style

F(n) * F(n+1) = prod, the number of n no more than one. I think your thought is ok, you can produce your fib list, meanwhile judge if f(n) * f(n+1) = prob, maybe your code can be simpler

```
prod = 50  # random value for your product
top_limit = int(prod ** 0.5)  # you should set a suitable top limit
def fib(top):
    n, a, b = 0, 0, 1
    while n < top:
        a, b = b, a + b
        if a * b == prod:
            yield [a,b,True]
        else:
            yield [a,b,False]
        n = n + 1
list(fib(top_limit))
```

And output is

```
[[1, 1, False],
 [1, 2, False],
 [2, 3, False],
 [3, 5, False],
 [5, 8, False],
 [8, 13, False],
 [13, 21, False]]
```

you see, 13 * 21 = 273 >> 50, you can set the variable `top_limit` even smaller